# test didn't pass yet: how to fix deprecation warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Initially, I had code that had DEPRECATION WARNINGS:

[Ruby on Rails: Deprecation Warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44740586/ruby-on-rails-deprecation-warnings)

I've changed this code to some extent, but I still have one warning left.

See the warning and code as below.
How to fix it and make sure all the tests pass? Thanks in advance.

DEPRECATION WARNING: Using positional arguments in integration tests has been deprecated,  ETA: 00:00:30
in favor of keyword arguments, and will be removed in Rails 5.1.

Deprecated style:
get "/profile", { id: 1 }, { "X-Extra-Header" => "123" }

New keyword style:
get "/profile", params: { id: 1 }, headers: { "X-Extra-Header" => "123" }
 (called from block (2 levels) in  at /home/ubuntu/workspace/origin/test/integration/following_test.rb:30)
  68/68: [=========================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:04, Time: 00:00:04

Finished in 4.25284s
68 tests, 336 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

```
require 'test_helper'

class FollowingTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user  = users(:michael)
    @other = users(:archer)
    log_in_as(@user)
  end

  test "following page" do
    get following_user_path(@user)
    assert_not @user.following.empty?
    assert_match @user.following.count.to_s, response.body
    @user.following.each do |user|
      assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(user)
    end
  end

  test "followers page" do
    get followers_user_path(@user)
    assert_not @user.followers.empty?
    assert_match @user.followers.count.to_s, response.body
    @user.followers.each do |user|
      assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(user)
    end
  end
test "should follow a user the standard way" do
    assert_difference '@user.following.count', 1 do
      post relationships_path, followed_id: @other.id
    end
  end

  test "should follow a user with Ajax" do
    assert_difference '@user.following.count', 1 do
      post relationships_path(followed_id: @other.id), xhr: true
    end
  end

  test "should unfollow a user the standard way" do
    @user.follow(@other)
    relationship = @user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @other.id)
    assert_difference '@user.following.count', -1 do
      delete relationship_path(relationship)
    end
  end

  test "should unfollow a user with Ajax" do
    @user.follow(@other)
    relationship = @user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @other.id)
    assert_difference '@user.following.count', -1 do
      delete relationship_path(relationship), xhr: true
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and Go Green... :D

```
require 'test_helper'

class FollowingTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user  = users(:michael)
    @other = users(:archer)
    log_in_as(@user)
  end

  test "following page" do
    get following_user_path(@user)
    assert_not @user.following.empty?
    assert_match @user.following.count.to_s, response.body
    @user.following.each do |user|
      assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(user)
    end
  end

  test "followers page" do
    get followers_user_path(@user)
    assert_not @user.followers.empty?
    assert_match @user.followers.count.to_s, response.body
    @user.followers.each do |user|
      assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(user)
    end
  end
test "should follow a user the standard way" do
    assert_difference '@user.following.count', 1 do
      post relationships_path, params: { followed_id: @other.id }
    end
  end

  test "should follow a user with Ajax" do
    assert_difference '@user.following.count', 1 do
      post relationships_path, params: { followed_id: @other.id }, xhr: true
    end
  end

  test "should unfollow a user the standard way" do
    @user.follow(@other)
    relationship = @user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @other.id)
    assert_difference '@user.following.count', -1 do
      delete relationship_path(relationship)
    end
  end

  test "should unfollow a user with Ajax" do
    @user.follow(@other)
    relationship = @user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @other.id)
    assert_difference '@user.following.count', -1 do
      delete relationship_path(relationship), xhr: true
    end
  end
end
```